# Docker can't find directory

Tags: python, docker

I want to create a docker for my scripts.

My `dockerfile` is =

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
    
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["main.py btcusdt"]
```

after set this Dockerfile,

```
sudo docker build -t image_name_test:tag_name_test .
```

my image id : 72e5ee15f5a5

```
sudo docker run 72e5ee15f5a5
```

and error is:

```
python3: can't open file 'main.py btcusdt': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why my docker can't find directory main.py ?

Thank you for your time.

Here is my files:

[image: here is my files]

Comment: Change `CMD ["main.py btcusdt"]` to `CMD ["./main.py", "btcusdt"]`. Hope that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quoting both the filename and its argument as a single word; it's the same effect as running without Docker

```bash
python3 "main.py btcusdt"
```

which causes the Python interpreter to look for that name, including the space and the argument, as the filename of the script to run.

If you're using the JSON-array "exec form", you need to split each word into a separate JSON array element.

This particular `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` split doesn't really make sense and I'd combine both halves into a single `CMD`.  So:

```bash
# no ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["python3", "main.py", "btcusdt"]
```

Better still, if you begin the script with a "shebang" line, as the very very first line of the script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and make the script executable

```bash
# on the host, committed to source control
chmod +x main.py
```

then you can omit the `python3` interpreter entirely

```bash
# still no ENTRYPOINT; still split into separate words
CMD ["./main.py", "btcusdt"]
```